# Ansible - remove the single quote (') character from a string

Tags: ansible-2.x

I'm new to `Ansible`, trying to use `Assert` module to validate the length
of a string. The result register contains string: `"'MWCC' | length == 3"`.

Could you please help to remove the single quotes `'` inside the string so the
result would be like this: `"MWCC | length == 3”`?

Thanks.

```
- set_fact:
    test_code: 'MWCC'

 - name: validate three characters code
   assert:
     that:
       "'{{test_code}}' | length == 3 "
   ignore_errors: True
   register: code_result

 - debug: var=code_result.assertion


 - name: extract the string from assertion test output
   set_fact:
     extract_result: "{{code_result.assertion |regex_replace('\'')}}"


TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "test_code": "MWCC"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [validate three characters code] ****************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "'MWCC' | length == 3 ",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false
}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "code_result.assertion": "'MWCC' | length == 3 "
}

TASK [extract the string from assertion test output] **********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u\"'\" at 41. String: {{code_result.assertion |regex_replace(''')}}"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"{{ test_string |replace(\"'\",'') }}"
```

This has the `replace` Jinja2 filter with two arguments:

1. the single quote, that you want to replace, surrounded by escaped double-quotes.
2. the empty string denoted by two single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assert should not have another pair of quotes, like this:

```
   "{{test_code}} | length == 3 "
```

And surely, 4 character string length should be 4, shouldn't it?

Comment: the above example was to simulate a fail condition that is why the 4 characters string was tested against length ==3.  I’d like to know how to strip off the single quotes(‘) inside that assertion output string: "'MWCC' | length == 3 "