# Unable to get stat of existing directory in Ansible due to variable formatting issue

Tags: ansible, runtime-error, parameter-passing, string-formatting, stat

I'm trying to get the owner of the first directory passed to Ansible variable `source_files`.

We do not have control over the content of Ansible variable `source_files` as it is constructed through some OLAM API. I have hard coded it for this example.

Both the  files of `source_files` variable exists as seen below:

```bash
[wluser@mylocalhost ~]$ ls -ltr '/tmp/my  private.txt' /tmp/files.sh  
-rw-r--r-- 1 wluser mygrp 0 Nov 12 21:52 /tmp/files.sh    
-rw-r--r-- 1 wluser mygrp 0 Nov 12 21:52 /tmp/my  private.txt
```

**Playbook** `[wluser@mylocalhost ~]$ cat formatstring.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: "Play 1-Find the details here"

  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: True
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

   - name: Set source_files variable
     set_fact:
       source_files: "'/tmp/my  private.txt','/tmp/files.sh'"
 
   - name: Print source_files
     debug:
       msg: "source_files: {{ source_files }}"
     
   - name: Loop Print source_files
     debug:
       msg: "{{ item }}"
     loop: "{{ source_files.split(',') }}"

   - name: Single Print source_files
     debug:
       msg: "{{ source_files.split(',')[0] }}"
   
   - name: Get directory owner
     ansible.builtin.stat:
       path: "{{ tomcat_home_item }}"
     register: dir_stat
     vars:
       tomcat_home_item: "{{ source_files.split(',')[0] | trim }}"

   - name: Store directory owner's UID in a variable
     set_fact:
       owner_uid: "{{ dir_stat.stat.pw_name | default('baduser') }}"

   - debug:
       msg: "Detected user is: {{ owner_uid }}"

   - name: Get directory owner
     ansible.builtin.stat:
       path: "{{ tomcat_home_item | regex_replace('^\\s*'|'\\s*$', '') }}"
     register: dir_stat
     vars:
       tomcat_home_item: "{{ source_files.split(',')[0] | trim }}"

   - name: Store directory owner's UID in a variable
     set_fact:
       owner_uid: "{{ dir_stat.stat.pw_name | default('baduser') }}"
 
   - debug:
       msg: "Detected user is: {{ owner_uid }}"
```

**Output**

```bash
[wluser@mylocalhost ~]$ ansible-playbook formatstring.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

```json
PLAYBOOK: formatstring.yml ****************************************************************************************************
1 plays in formatstring.yml

PLAY [Play 1-Find the details here] *******************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Set source_files variable] **********************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:10
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:56 -0600 (0:00:00.044)       0:00:00.044 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "source_files": "'/tmp/my  private.txt','/tmp/files.sh'"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Print source_files] *****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:15
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:56 -0600 (0:00:00.018)       0:00:00.062 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "source_files: '/tmp/my  private.txt','/tmp/files.sh'"
}

TASK [Loop Print source_files] ************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:19
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:56 -0600 (0:00:00.017)       0:00:00.080 *******
ok: [localhost] => (item='/tmp/my  private.txt') => {
    "msg": "'/tmp/my  private.txt'"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item='/tmp/files.sh') => {
    "msg": "'/tmp/files.sh'"
}

TASK [Single Print source_files] **********************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:24
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:56 -0600 (0:00:00.033)       0:00:00.114 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "'/tmp/my  private.txt'"
}

TASK [Get directory owner] ****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:29
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:56 -0600 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.137 *******
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: wluser
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
            "follow": false,
            "get_attributes": true,
            "get_checksum": true,
            "get_md5": null,
            "get_mime": true,
            "path": "'/tmp/my  private.txt'"
        }
    },
    "stat": {
        "exists": false
    }
}

TASK [Store directory owner's UID in a variable] ******************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:36
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:57 -0600 (0:00:00.352)       0:00:00.489 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "owner_uid": "baduser"
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:40
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:57 -0600 (0:00:00.020)       0:00:00.510 *******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Detected user is: baduser"
}

TASK [Get directory owner] ****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/wluser/formatstring.yml:43
Sunday 12 November 2023  22:02:57 -0600 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.529 *******
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'name', got 'string'. String: {{ tomcat_home_item | regex_replace('^\\\\s*'|'\\\\s*$', '') }}"
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ************************************************************************************************************
PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see, I'm getting `baduser` instead of correct user `wluser` due to quoting/formatting issues with variable `source_files`.

I then attempted to remove the quotes but that got me runtime error.

Can you please suggest how can i get the stats to the file considering the formatting of source_files mentioned initially in the playbook cannot be changed.

Comment: "_We do not have control over Ansible variable `source_files` as it is constructed through some OLAM API._" Can you show the real content of `source_files`? With the currently given information it is not possible to reproduce an issue for me.

Comment: @U880D u can run the code as is and be able to reproduce the error with ansible 2.7.8 I have set_fact sources_files as is printed by my play so there is no difference

Comment: No, that's why I've asked. You are setting the variable content in a `set_fact` task. For me it is in this stage not clear if that is output of the OLAM API or not.

Comment: @U880D I copied the output from Olam they way it's printed and using that as set_fact for this testcase which is reproducible. I made a video where I simply copy paste from this post on  stack overflow  and run the play. Here: https://youtu.be/pA1xo5Vu4Tg?feature=shared

Comment: I do not understand the advantage of making a video were you show something is copy and pasted instead of copy and paste it here by editing the initial question and description, including detail of what is the exact output of your OLAM API and how you have gathered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How can I get the stats to the file considering the formatting of `source_files`***

Assuming the output of the `ls -ltr` command is correct, as well the content of `source_files`. For files

```bash
~/test$ ls -ltr 'test file' 'test path' 'test path/test file'
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 0 Nov 13 08:00 test file
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 0 Nov 13 08:00 test path/test file

test path:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 0 Nov 13 08:00 test file
```

a minimal example playbook

````yaml
```---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FILE: 'test file'
    PATH: 'test path'

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      SOURCE_FILES: "'test file','test path/test file'"

  - stat:
      path: 'test file'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stat.path }}"

  - stat:
      path: "{{ FILE }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stat.path }}"

  - stat:
      path: "{{ PATH }}/{{ FILE }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stat.path }}"

  - debug:
      msg:
        - "Content: {{ SOURCE_FILES }}"
        - "Type: {{ SOURCE_FILES | type_debug }}"
        - "List of files: {{ SOURCE_FILES | split(',') }}"

  - stat:
      path: "{{ SOURCE_FILES | split(',') | first | replace(\"'\",'') }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stat.path }}"

  - stat:
      path: "{{ SOURCE_FILES | split(',') | last | replace(\"'\",'') }}"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stat.path }}"
````

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [stat] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test file

TASK [stat] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test file

TASK [stat] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test path/test file

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - 'Content: ''test file'',''test path/test file'''
  - 'Type: AnsibleUnicode'
  - 'List of files: [u"''test file''", u"''test path/test file''"]'

TASK [stat] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test file

TASK [stat] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test path/test file
```

If the content of `source_files` is a Comma Separated Value (CSV) string with explicit quoted values and quote character `single quote (')` <sub>*(... annot: which it makes non-RFC conform then)*</sub>, to make a list of file names out of it again

- Split on delimiter comma (`,`) via `split(',')`
- Remove the explicit quote character `single quote (')` for all values via `replace(\"'\",'')`

Please take not that files can not contain single quote anymore as that would run into an error again. It would fail in example for

```bash
~/test$ touch "andrew's.file"
~/test$ ls -al and*
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 0 Nov 13 09:30 andrew's.file
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 0 Nov 13 09:30 and.yml
```

**Thanks To**

- [RFC 4180 "Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)
- [Ansible - Remove the single quote (`'`) character from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690010/6771046)

Comment: whatever we pass to Olam  gets enclosed in double quotes as passed as parameter to ansible so `passvar=value one` will go to ansible Play as `- e passvar="valueone"`. Keeping this into mind what is a better way of passing and reading white space file/folder paths into ansible play? Kindly suggest? I thought of enclosing them in single quotes so whitespace in filenames are maintained and separated by comma. Would like to have expert / other suggestions to make this a better solution? Note i don't control OLam but simply pass parameters recieved from github actions - > olam - > ansible

Comment: "_I thought of enclosing them in single quotes so whitespace in filenames are maintained and separated by comma._", one can define any data structure which works for him as long as one stick to 'em during the whole processing. Issue arising usually if there are changes in data structures or during different processing steps are different structures expected. And especially over different (operating) systems.